# how to accurately update the text field's attribute upon removal?

Tags: jquery, html, paypal

Ok, this is an attempt to update the name attribute of text fields upon removal.

(no knowledge of jquery/js)

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcxL98Lz/)

Currently, as the script stands, the name's attribute `os0` increments upon user's addition of text field.

But, say you generate 4 of them, and then randomly remove `Name 2`, yes, the name labels gets updated to reflect the text fields left, but the text fields' name attribute `os2` gets removed, and the numbers are left are not sequential. It would end up being `on0`, `on2`, and `on3`.

How do I fix the jquery's removal script part so the name attributes accurately reflect the removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it. Every time you remove an inputfield it iterates through the remaining inputfields and reassigns the `name`-attribute with `on` + the indexnumber.

**Edit:** The labels `for`-attribute and the inputs `id`-attribute updates now too

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var maxFields = 10;
  $('.my-form .add-box').click(function() {
    var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
    if (n > maxFields) {
      alert('Field limit reached');
      return;
    }
    var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Box <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="on' + (n - 1) + '" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>');
    box_html.hide();
    $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');

  });

  $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#FF6C6C').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).remove();
      $('.text-box').each(function(index) {
        var label = $(this).children('label');
        label.attr('for', 'box' + (index + 1));
        label.children('.box-number').text(index + 1);
        $(this).children('input').attr({
          name: 'on' + index,
          id: 'box' + (index + 1)
        });
      });
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-form">
  <form role="form" method="post">
    <p class="text-box">
      <label for="box1">Box <span class="box-number">1</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="on0" value="" id="box1" />
      <a class="add-box" href="#">Add More</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you again! I have a couple of more questions that I have to solve. Will post it later today. Hope you can help with it!

Comment: here's another question if you have the inclination to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257040/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-text-fields-created

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just let me know.

Comment: eh, it got migrated because of the way I wrote the question. Sigh. Plus, I had done the modification myself this time instead of asking how to do it. Anyway, here's the link if you want to look at it: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102127/limiting-the-number-of-text-fields-created

Comment: I've updated my post with a field limit as you asked in the question :), if you don't want to show an alert, just remove that one line but keep the `return`.

Comment: hey, sorry for the late response. Thank you for your update! I'm using your version. Since you didn't reply on the other thread, I upvoted your answer. =)

Comment: No problem, it's a bit of a hassle to create a new account to answer one question, so that's why I updated this post. Works just fine. If you need any help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the function to remove textbox in your fiddle

```
$('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
$(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
$(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).nextAll().each(function(){
        $(this).find('input').attr('name','on'+(parseInt($(this).find('input').attr('name').split('on')[1])-1).toString());
    });
    $(this).remove();
    $('.box-number').each(function(index){
        $(this).text( index + 1 );
    });
});
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/wcxL98Lz/1/)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond! Appreciate it.